# Trying to alter ALT tags in a View

Tags: views

I have a view that contains images, I need to slightly alter the alt tag for each image by amending some text from the url onto the end. I seem to have pretty much figured it out yet when I check the view it has not altered anything.

Here is the code in my custom module, I have tried using a HOOK_views_post_execute and HOOK_views_pre_render, but still isn't changing the alt tags in the view

```
function image_alt_tag_alter_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if ($view->name == "we_print_for_menu") {
    $path == arg(0) . "/" . arg(1);
    $alias = drupal_get_path_alias($path);


    // loops through index in array to change each alt tag
    // I have echo'd out from this loop and it is changing successfully
    // It just won't render in the view
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($view->result); ++$i) {
    $view->result[$i]->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_image_front_menu['und'][0]['alt'] == $view->result[$i]->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_image_front_menu['und'][0]['alt'] . $alias;
  }
    // not sure if I need this
    return $view;



}
```

Comment: You're using comparison (`==`) instead of assignment (`=`) when you're trying to set the var. That's probably the only problem

Comment: Hi Clive, yes I missed that somehow woops. Unfortunately that hasn't helped, still the alt tags won't update :(

Comment: You have the == on the $path as well as the $view variable, did you fix both?

Comment: Thanks Laryn :), yes I did, if I echo out all the changed alt values after the loop they have updated correctly. Yet the view does not render this way, it just remains as it was before..

Comment: I can't figure this out, $view->attachment_before and $view->attachment_after are both working within the hook.. In the hook instructions it just states that you need to edit $view->result, which I have done, within the function it is printing out with the correctly amended value, yet it isn't taking affect in the view.